# Hibernate JPA not creating table automatically in wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly-9

My Persistence xml looks like

```
<properties> 

  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

</properties>
```

Only error found in wildfly server is :

```
 HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

Comment: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/> , Here i also tried with value ="create"/"update"

Comment: Error says "hibernate.properties not found'. Looks like it's not able to read the properties file. Do post the snippet where you read the properties file.